# How can I find the center of a canvas in js

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have `canvas`. I have a `ctx`. I want the `ctx` to draw in the **center** of the `canvas`, however

```
canvas.height/2
canvas.width/2
```

does not work

http://jsfiddle.net/3hnbarcg/3/

Also, I need proof It works before I can accept

Comment: You may need to learn how to write basic HTML and JS to pass your assignment.

Comment: The jsfiddle link does not show how canvas.height/2 and canvas.width/2 aren't working as expected.

Comment: I put wrong link fixed now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at following code.

```js
var centerPointWidth = 10;
var centerPointHeight = 10;
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillRect((canvas.width / 2) - (centerPointWidth / 2), (canvas.height / 2) - (centerPointHeight / 2), centerPointWidth, centerPointHeight);
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

It works perfectly to draw a rectangle at the center of the canvas.